# Fatal Error on Symfony 2 CRUD command

Tags: crud, fatal-error

Good Mourning!

I have an error while performing the CRUD command, I see this error in the console.

```
Fatal error: Class 'Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Mapping\MetadataFactory'
not found in [route-to-project]\vendor\sensio\generator-bundle\Sensio\Bundle
\GeneratorBundle\Command\GenerateDoctrineCommand.php on line 36
```

[searching the web](http://www.tools-geek.fr/blog/2014/04/20/class-doctrinebundledoctrinebundlemappingmetadatafactory-not-found-in-generatedoctrinecommand-php/) I found that the upgrade Doctrine is not compatible with the bundle of sensiogenerator and should rollback to a previous version.

But I can not do it because I have several installed bundles that are not compatible with an early version of doctrine.

I hava a solution or I have to create the controllers manually?

Thank you!

this is my composer.json

```
{
"name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
},
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.4.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "2.*",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.3.*@dev",
    "twig/extensions": "1.*",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~1.3",        
    "sonata-project/cache-bundle" : "dev-master",
    "sonata-project/intl-bundle" : "dev-master",
    "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "~2.1",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "2.*",
    "sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle": "2.*",
    "sonata-project/user-bundle": "2.2.*@dev",
    "sonata-project/block-bundle": "~2.2,>=2.2.7",
    "sonata-project/core-bundle": "~2.2@dev",        
    "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": ">=1.1.0,<3.0.0",
    "knplabs/knp-menu": ">=1.1.0,<3.0.0",
    "sonata-project/jquery-bundle": "1.8.*",
    "sonata-project/exporter": "1.3.3",

    "whiteoctober/tcpdf-bundle":"dev-master",
    "knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle": "*"

},
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin"
},
"minimum-stability": "stable",
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "incenteev-parameters": {
        "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
    },
    "branch-alias": {
        "dev-master": "2.3-dev"
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution! Just create a MetadataFactory.php file in vendor\doctrine\doctrine-bundle\Doctrine\DoctrineBundle\Mapping whit the MetadataFactory class

[here the file](https://mega.co.nz/#!VB5jHKiR!n96GND70zT2mRngPjEvnsfEqe0UV-PREHTAy7vyYoXs)

Answer (score 1):

**Better Solution**

Anyone using Symfony 2.7 or lower might run into this.

[Here is the commit where the problem was fixed](https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioGeneratorBundle/pull/231/files)

You could patch this directly to your codebase, but modifying core vendor files makes composer redundant.

A better solution is to upgrade the `SensioGeneratorBundle` to `v2.5`, which appears to be compatible with Symfony `v2.7`

In `composer.json` change this: `"sensio/generator-bundle": "2.5.*"`

Then run `composer update` (*be warned - this will update everything in your composer file, which may not be desirable.*)

**Alternative Solution**

Only update a single package

`composer require sensio/generator-bundle:2.5.3`